# what if i want to add two icons to one button by using jquery-ui 1.12.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-button

```
  $("#search_button").button({
    icons: {
        "primary": 'ui-icon-search',
        "secondary": "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
    },
});
```

`"secondary": "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"` can't be added to  `"#search_button"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update code to work with new jquery ui version 1.12.0

//Old

```
<button>Click me</button>

$( "button" ).button( {
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-lock",
        secondary: "ui-icon-gear"
    }
} );
```

//In new ui version 1.12.0

```
<button>Click me <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear"></span></button>

$( "button" ).button( {
    icon: "ui-icon-lock"
} );
```

```js
$("#search_button" ).button( {
    icon: "ui-icon-search"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="search_button">Search <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></button>
```